# Replace text inside html tag (not between) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I see a lot of reference for replacing text between tags or replacing tags identified with an ID, but my task is quite different in that I need to replace part of the tag itself. For example, I want to change...

```
<body etc>
```

So that it becomes...

```
<body somestring etc>
```

The change needs to be performed in the browser using JavaScript, ie: after a CMS (like Wordpress) has finished with it.

Comment: You are looking to change *attributes* in HTML.

Comment: Nothing yet because I just realised that my question seems to be about setting an attribute like id=xyz when what I really need is the freedom to inject a string that might call a JS function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to add new attribute to DOM element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("id", "something");
```

Answer (score 3):

`document['getElementsByTagName']('html')[0]['setAttribute']('attr', 'value');`

Comment: What's the advantage of adding []? Also, how can I use this to add multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can accomplish this with a line like the following:

```
$("html").attr({foo:"bar", baz:"bing"});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run a wordpress website you might already be using jquery. With JQuery this is something easy

```
$('html').attr('id', 'bob');
//just for testing
alert($('html').attr('id'));
```

Comment: This looks like it might work inserting an ID, but what if it was applied to another tag, for example the BODY tag to insert an onLoad statement like:

    <body onLoad="someFunction();">

Comment: If you are using Jquery then you can simply  
`
$(document).ready(function() {
 //whatever you want
});
`
you can also tie things to on click
`
$("#other").click(function() {
  alert('hellooo');
});
`

Comment: You can find more info about what attributes you can change and how here [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/) or about events here [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the value of standard attributes, just use DOM properties:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].id = 'foo';
```

or more simply:

```
document.documentElement.id = 'foo';
```

It's not a good idea to set non–standard attributes or properties, use [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attributes instead.